# Duplicate stdin to stdout and stderr (synchronized)

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, stderr, duplicate-data

I need to duplicate the stdout of a producer and feed it to two consumer in a **synchronized** fashion.

```
                        consumer 1
producer | duplicator | 
                        consumer 2
```

This can easily be accomplished for example via a dup.c program doing the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size;
    while (getline(&line, &size, stdin) != -1) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", line);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and then:

```
(cat file.txt | ./dup | ./consumer1.py ; ) 2>&1 | ./consumer2.py
```

However, **if consumer 1 is faster than consumer 2 we have a problem**. E.g., consumer 1 is already at line 50,000 while consumer 2 is at line 17,000. If I "tail -f" the output of consumer1.py and consumer2.py we can see that because consumer2.py is slower (due to heavy processings inside)

output consumer1.py at time x:

```
50,546
50,547
50,548
50,549
50,550
50,551
50,552
```

output consumer2.py at time x:

```
17,315
17,316
17,317
17,318
17,319
17,320
17,321
```

For my system **I need that both consumers are at the same line, hence the faster consumer needs to be restricted**. It should be somehow possible. Any suggestions how to accomplish this? Maybe via signal handling or pipe specific voodoo? Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns here. Why do you need the consumers to be synchronized? What do they produce? Why can't you combine the consumers into a single program? Why can't consumers sync among themselves if they need it so much? Btw, there's a command line utility `tee` for doing the same.

Comment: Write yourself a python script doing what you want. Why waste time on making shell pipes do your bidding if you are done 10 times faster with a small python script?

Comment: You don't need `dup.c`, you should use `tee(1)` instead. Rely on common UNIX tools, don't write custom small programs like this. Now, onto your specific problem: I don't think you can do this without either changing the producer code or the consumers code. The consumers could be synchronized with pthread barriers (or the equivalent in python) if you change your code such that both consumers run in the same process but in different threads. Alternatively, you can change the producer to emit new data only after both of the consumers acknowledge that processing is done for the line.

Comment: Thank you @mojuba. Here are some answers: I want consumer1 to kill consumer2 after a specific number of lines. consumer2 is a binary I can not change. consumer1 is my own program. The producer produces strings terminated by \n. I'm aware of tee and some other solutions for this job.

Comment: Thank you @BitTickler. I'm aware of the possibility of binding duplicator's stdout to consumer1 and duplicator's stderr to consumer2 via python and subprocess. Actually, I do it this way. For the simplicity of explanation I did not write this here.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I'm aware of tee and other solutions for this problem. However, they can not accomplish this synchronized thing either. I already asked this in the UNIX section of stackoverflow. They suggested that the only possible way would be to write my own version of tee, what I did here. Do you know "how to acknowledge" that processing is done for the line? Actually, thats exactly what I thought of before posting this question here. However, until now, nobody were able to tell me how to know, that consumer1 has successfully read the line from its stdin.

Comment: @m33x You can also simply spawn 2 sub-processes in pyhton, then read your stdin in your script, write it to both pipes to the 2 respective sub-processes, then read the 2 sub-processes and once you got both replies, you write the numbers to stdout. Functional-programming-lingo: You zip both results, which are produced by lock-stepped asynchronous workers.